# How can I mend my metal tables broken arm?

Tags: repair

Hi I have a Metal table with **two Arms** that **protrude outwards and Up** of which you can place a cup and small plate on or Similar (Great for keeping the main table clear) but one of the Kids fell and broke Part of the arm, now **Super Glue is not Stromg enough** and Im trying to find an extreamly hard Bonding agent Apart from Welding, that will hold the two seperate metals together.
Thanks

Comment: A broken part that requires good lateral strength (versus tensile strength) is going to be difficult or impossible to repair with any kind of glue or epoxy. That is, the shearing force exerted on the arm will just cause it to fail at the weakest point again -- that is the point where it broke and you repaired it. The force acts on it like a lever and puts tremendous stress at that point. If this is made of steel you could have it spot welded or you could fix it with a sleeve of some kind, but anything will be ugly...

Answer (score 3):

A photo would help us visualize the broken part, but provided there's enough surface area, JB Weld should work. It's an epoxy that can join metals.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU Extreamly helpful will Order some Tonight (I am Housebound due to Severe Injuries)

Comment: A Hunch is that the metal is actually a cast iron. which will be hard to weld in any case... the other option is to make up some sort of brace where you use screws or rivits to attach a brace over the break..

Comment: JB Weld claims to work with cast iron.